# jQuery UI: "base is not a constructor"

Tags: jquery-ui, npm, jquery-ui-selectable

I've installed jQuery and jQuery UI with `npm`. Upon attempting to `require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable')` in one of my own JS modules, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: base is not a constructor (widget.js:108)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Also had this problem with `jQRangeSlider 5.5.0`. Your solution works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the issue, I also had to `require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse')` which is a dependency for `selectable` but not loaded automatically when requiring the latter.

Comment: And the same thing with `yarn`!